# Closing cURL in PHP

Tags: php, curl

I have 3 questions about cURL in PHP:

1. How do I check if a cURL handle is an open connection?
2. Does PHP automatically close cURL connections?
3. Are there any drawbacks to not calling `curl_close()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets answer starting from the easiest one

Yes, PHP closes the connection, at least from his endpoint, the other side of the connection may have a delay on closing it or freeing the sockets or freeing the process thread already used, but PHP closes the connection when the garbage collector works at the end of the scope/function/script that executed cURL.

Drawbacks for not calling curl_close() depend on how is your script working/behaving, if your script is doing something that keeps it open/working, then you are using resources, CPU cycles, RAM and sockets, that may or may not be relevant depending on each situation, but we can agree that is a good practice to free resources as soon as possible. Specially if you are in a restricted or very limited environment like a shared hosting where RAM and sockets may not be abundant. This may be aggravated if you use the multi options, like curl_multi_init, curl_multi_exec, etc.

About if it's an open connection, I'm not completely sure, but I suppose that you can use some of the information obtained with curl_getinfo and compare, for instance against the size of the transfer and what you already have or the time is taking

Answer (score 0):

curl handle is a resource, using is_resource can help you.
Even if php does closes the handle on its own, I don't think calling curl_close() has any drawbacks. 
Please Note: I have no idea whatsoever that PHP closes the curl handle on its own or not, but I personally feel curl_close is a good way of ending things.! :)

Happy coding!!